# Deployment error. [info] Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file index.js can't be loaded

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've been trying to use firebase as a backend for my projects and I'm getting this error and I'm not able to decipher it or find a way to solve it . Below is the debug log for it.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IOqbw_WiY75xP1zNKiuhS4vcVRsbGAZApxnHES-fPx4/edit?usp=drivesdk

You can skip to line 216 , that's where errors start and after line 229 it's just the errors repeating themselves in forthcoming functions.

Comment: To get the proper assistance from other users, you would need to provide more context to your situation, such as what you are expecting, what you have tried, some structure, etc. It might also be worth only including the error message you have observed instead of providing an entire log and to look for the proper line, when there are no line numbers to the Google Doc. However, from the error message you are seeing, it might be related to this resolved [Stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61334588/cloud-functions-deployment-error-function-failed-on-loading-user-code-error-me).

Comment: Thanks a lot i solved this error a few hours ago although i hate firebase for its misleading errors . All i did was remove the service account thing from index.js as it was not able to locate it and set my initialize app to apply the default settings for the properties

Answer (score 0):

All i did was remove the service account thing from index.js as it was not able to locate it and set my initialize app to apply the default settings for the properties .
Tada it solved my error